# How can I display facebook comment box in my ionic cordova hybrid app

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, facebook-javascript-sdk, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using ionic cordova for my hybrid mobile app development. I have added below in my index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src =   "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=4180553387979979380746";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

and this is the html where i want to display comment box

```
<div class="fb-comments" dyn-fb-comment-box data-mobile="true" data-width="100%" page-href="https://facebook.com/" data-numposts="15"></div>
```

When I test it in chrome, it is working fine with no problem, but when i do

```
ionic build android and install the .apk file in my mobile, facebook comment box is not displayed at all.
```

Can anyone help me what I am missing here?

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I am having same problem.

Comment: No, instead I went for disqus. which is easy to implement.

Comment: try like this https://codepen.io/ethanneff/pen/yymYRR